# Мониторинг значений конкретных адресов в label

Tags: c#

Допустим, создали форму с 10 label. В каждый из них нам нужно вести мониторинг конкретных значений из адресов памяти определенного процесса.Чтобы все 10 label были активными и постоянно проверяли значение адреса и выводили его на экран в label. Поиск значения в конкретном адресе осуществляется следующим образом и таких адресов 10:

```
var Address = api.ReadPointer(api.GetModuleAddress("server.dll"), new[] { 0x02211338, 0x2F8, 0x6A0, 0x7B0, 0x438, 0x120 });
var Addr1 = 0;
Addr1 = vam.ReadInt32(Address);
```

Значение Addr1 показать в 1 label и так все 10, но чтобы они мониторили значения постоянно с задержкой максимум 0.2-0.5 секунды.

Как это реализовать? Помогите пожалуйста. C# изучаю второй день и нет опыта правильно написать программу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В C# (да и не только) есть чудная штука для решения переодических проблем - таймер. На msdn есть [пример его использования](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3tszykws(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Адаптируем.

Вначале поставим на форму элемент управления Timer

Теперь его нужно настроить (Это можно сделать и в свойствах)

```
private void InitializeTimer()
{
   timer1.Interval = 1000; // вызывать раз в секунду
   timer1.Enabled = true; // он должен быть точно включен
   // важная часть - прицепить обработчик
   this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
}
```

Если интервал нужен 0.2 секунды, то вместо 1000 присваиваем 200. Ставить значение интервала меньше 50 нет смысла.

этот метод нужно не забыть вызывать перед началом "обновления". Если же все свойства настраиваются мышкой, то наверно правильно таймер вначале выключить (enable = false) и включить только когда будет нужно.

Теперь остался второй этап - это написать обработчик.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
  // здесь будет код
}
```

его имя timer1_Tick как раз упоминается в предыдущем куске кода и это обычное имя для автосгенерированного кода.

Теперь дело осталось за малым - внутри обработчика вписать нужный код, который будет читать значения и вписывать их в label.